# Given a hex string (0xNNNNNNNN), what is the simplest way to modify a certain bit in GNU make?

Tags: makefile

I'm currently working in a makefile.

I have a hex string, in the format 0xNNNNNNNN.

I would like to set the 32nd bit to 1. Given 0x00000000, I would like to turn it into 0x00010000

I know I could do this by calling an external script in my favorite scripting lanuage, but I was wondering if there was a simpler way to do this within the makefile itself, or by calling a pre-existing Linux utility.

Comment: That is the 17th bit, given the four zeros after it, denoting 4 bit nybbles.

Answer (score 1):

Make can't do this directly (although you could use something like [this](http://gmsl.sourceforge.net)), the simplest method IMO is to just use the shell, although it's not going to be completely portable

```
hex := 0x00000000
hex != printf '0x%x' $$(( $(hex) | 1 << 31 ))
$(info $(hex))
```

Your example sets the 17th bit, I'm guessing you meant 0x80000000.

Comment: Base conversion is supported by some shells, but is not POSIX.  For a portable solution, maybe use Perl instead.  `hex = $(shell perl -e 'printf "%08x\n", $(hex) | 1 << 31')`

Comment: @tripleee I think if you need to support non-bash shells then you'll probably need to take into account that something as ubiquitous as perl might not be installed either :)

Comment: Awk or `bc` then, perhaps; but anything installed in the last 15 years should have Perl, in my experience.